# Proving equivalence of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I feel like I have proved the following statement but I am unsure.

**Statement:** For all sets $A,B,$ $A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$.

**Proof:** Let $A,B$, be sets. Let $x\in (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
x\in (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)&\equiv x\in A\setminus B \ \lor \ x\in A\cap B\\
&\equiv (x\in A \ \land \ x \not \in B) \ \lor \ (x\in A \ \land \ x\in B)\\
&\equiv x\in A \ \land \ (x\not \in B \ \lor \ x\in B)\\
&\equiv x\in A \ \land \ (x\in \overline B \cup B)\\
&\equiv x\in A
\end{align*}
I feel like the last step is somewhat of a leap.

Comment: There's a typo in your third step, but apart from that I would accept this as a proof.

Comment: To help with your last step, $x\in\overline{B}\cup B\equiv TRUE$.  And, in general $y\land TRUE\equiv y$.

Comment: Thanks Michael! But I'm not familiar with TRUE. What is it?

Comment: I fixed the (obvious) typo.....TRUE means a sentence that is always true. An instance, known as the excluded middle, occurs in the proof: .... $S\lor \neg S$ is true regardless of what $S$ is.

Comment: Do you have a universal set? If not, assume it, namely that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a large,large set $P$,which you consider your universe. Now $B^c = P - B$. Use this to complete your proof.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $B\cup \overline B$ is simply the universal set? Therefore, we know that x is in A and the universe. Which is really just A.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to prove two sets, A and B, are equal is to show that A is a subset of B and that B is a subset of A.  And to prove A is a subset of B, start "if x is in A" and use the definitions and properties of A and B to conclude "x is in B.

To show that A is a subset of $(A\ B)\cup (A\cap B)$, if x is in A then there are two cases:
1) x is in B.  Then x is in $A\cap B$ so in $(A\ B)\cup (A\cap B)$.
2) x is not in B.  Then x is in A\ B so in $(A\ B)\cup (A\cap B)$.
  In either case, if x is in A, then x is in $(A\ B)\cup (A\cap B)$ so $A\subset (A\ B)\cup (A\cap B)$.

Now, if x is in $(A\ B)\cup (A\cap B)$ then there are two cases:
1) x is in A\ B. Then x is in A and not in B.
2) x is in $A\cap B$.  The x is in A and in B.
  In either case x is in A so $(A\ B)\cup (A\cap B)\subset A$.

Comment: Thanks for posting this alternative way of solving the problem!